# Win32 WndProc Name: why can't I change its name?

Tags: winapi

I have compiled a simple win32 app successfully with bc++ (2 lines excerpt only):

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure (HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

wincl.lpfnWndProc = WindowProcedure;
```

Why can't I rename WindowProcedure and compile this:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc (HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

wincl.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
```

as error message gives:

> Turbo Incremental Link 5.00 Copyright
>   (c) 1997, 2000 Borland Error:
>   Unresolved external '**stdcall
>   WndProc(HWND** *, unsigned int,
>   unsigned int, long)' referenced from
>   C:\PROGRAMMING\SALLY\WIN32TUTORIAL\MAIN.OBJ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a linker error, not a compiler error.  It looks like you have renamed the declaration but not the definition.  You need to rename the definition (the part that includes the {body of the function}).

Comment: sorry I'm absolute beginner. Do I have to change something in windows.h perhaps ?

Comment: If you do a text search for WindowProcedure in your project, are there any hits?

Comment: OK thank you it was at the end I didn't see it in the first place.